# How can I run C-code with assembly inserts

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, inline-assembly, intel-syntax

I have C-program with assembly insert.
Here is code:
main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f() {
    int a = 0, b;
    __asm__ (".intel_syntax noprefix\n\t"
             "mov edx, 1\n\t"
             :"=r"(b)
             :"r"(a)
             :"eax"
            );
    return b;
}

int  main() {
    printf("%d", f());
}
```

I have found out how to compile this code (*gcc -std=c11 -S  main.c -o main*), but when i run it (*./main*) - here is a problem in terminal:
*bash: ./main: Permission denied.*

When I try to compile it without -S flag, I get many unreasonable mistakes:

```
/tmp/ccw3H0Mb.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccw3H0Mb.s:23: Error: Instruction does not exist: «movl%edx,-4(%rbp)»
/tmp/ccw3H0Mb.s:24: Error: Instruction does not exist: «movl4(%rbp),%eax»
/tmp/ccw3H0Mb.s:46: Error: Instruction does not exist: «movl$0,%eax»
/tmp/ccw3H0Mb.s:48: Error: Instruction does not exist: «movl%eax,%esi»
/tmp/ccw3H0Mb.s:49: Error: Garbage «(%rip)» after expression
/tmp/ccw3H0Mb.s:50: Error: Instruction does not exist: «movl$0,%eax»
/tmp/ccw3H0Mb.s:52: Error: Instruction does not exist: «movl$0,%eax»
```

What is the error and how can I fix it to run my code correctly?
Thanks! :)

Comment: The option `-S` causes assembly code to be generated.  It does not produce a binary.  Remove the option `-S` and you should obtain a binary that can be executed.

Comment: Your inline asm is broken.  You hard-code `edx`, but you tell the compiler it can pick any register for the output operand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed was just adding *-masm=intel* to the compilation command, and, of course, I removed -S flag (thanks to *fuz*). It is important because I am using Intel syntax, so gcc must be awared about it.

Now it looks like:

```
gcc -std=c11 -masm=intel main.c -o main
```